# Run a marko in a second Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I programming sth. in Excel vba that opens from a excel file a second excel file and call a function in the second excel file --> looks like that

```
Workbooks.Open excelPath 
Application.Run(excelPath & "!RequestFunc", String1, String2)
```

It works fine so far but the problem is I have to configure the macro security configurations that I always accept to use macros but this is not possible in my case.

I need a solution where I can automatically active the macros in the second file or that the user get ask to activate them.<-- If I have the Development IDE of MS-Excel open the user get ask but if the IDE is closed there is just an Error coming that the marcos are deactivated and its not possible to call this macro...

Any ideas ?
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the filename without the path when you're building the function name to pass to `Application.Run`:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(excelPath)
Application.Run wb.Name & "!RequestFunc", String1, String2
```

Comment: I get the same error. That macros of the opened file are deactivated. The user just get ask to activate the macros if the Programming Window of excel is open but the normal user will not have open is Window..